# Django Test assertTemplateUsed() failed: AssertionError: No templates used to render the response

Tags: django, testing, django-templates

I have an About page and written a test against it. The template renders well in the browser while the `assertTemplatedUsed` failed even the template name, url name and status code (returns 200) are all correct. Which part went wrong?

Thank you!

The error below:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
...F......
======================================================================
FAIL: test_aboutpage_template (pages.tests.AboutPageTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/pages/tests.py", line 54, in test_aboutpage_template
    self.assertTemplateUsed(self.response, 'about.html')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 655, in assertTemplateUsed
    self.fail(msg_prefix + "No templates used to render the response")
AssertionError: No templates used to render the response

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 10 tests in 0.070s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

My `test.py`:

```
class AboutPageTests(SimpleTestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        url = reverse('about')
        self.response = self.client.get(url)


    def test_aboutpage_status_code(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, 200)


    def test_aboutpage_template(self):
        self.assertTemplateUsed(self.response, 'about.html')
```

Comment: what is the result of `print(self.response.__dict__)` inside `test_aboutpage_template` ? is there any problem to test with `self.assertEqual(self.response.templates[0].name, "about.html")`?

Comment: Oh thanks! I found the result of `print(self.response.__dict__)`  `{'templates': [], ...}`. No wonder the assertion failed. Thank you!